# How to handle routes Heroku Create React App with express?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, create-react-app

I have a create-react-app project which proxies a node express server at port 5000.

When we deploy it locally, all the requests get routed from client to the backend server and intermediate pages get rendered properly.

However, when I deploy it to Heroku, the flow always has to start from / route as any other URL directly hits the express server instead of being routed from front end.

Eg: https://consumesafe-dev.herokuapp.com works

But https://consumesafe-dev.herokuapp.com/dashboard goes directly to the node server instead of being proxied from front end.

here is the package.json for server:

```
{
  "name": "example-create-react-app-express",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "client": "cd client && yarn start",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "test": "cd client && npm install && yarn test",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"yarn server\" \"yarn client\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/language": "^1.0.0",
    "@google-cloud/vision": "^0.12.0",
    "async": "^2.6.0",
    "body-parser": "~1.4.2",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "google-cloud": "^0.57.0",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "method-override": "~2.0.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.3",
    "pg": "^7.4.1",
    "request": "^2.83.0",
    "sequelize": "^4.37.2",
    "winston": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.5.1"
  }
}
```

and the package.json from client:

```
{
  "name": "example-create-react-app-express",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000/",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "firebase": "^3.6.1",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-checkbox-group": "^4.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-event-timeline": "^1.5.1",
    "react-notification-system": "^0.2.17",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your server.js content?

Comment: Is your app Client rendered or Server rendered? If it's server rendered you need to have routes defined in your express config. Otherwise for client side routing, you need to have just a static server serving up you index.html ( mapped to your build folder ).